# AlarmManager with ContentObserver

Tags: android, android-alarms

How can we set an `AlarmManager`, for a `ContentObserver` class in `PendingIntent`?

Possible methods are :

```
  PendingIntent.getActivity

  PendingIntent.getService

  PendingIntent.getBroadCast
```

So, which one to use if it is at all possible?

Comment: added the ans. please be more specific and Elaborative while asking question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PendingIntent.getBroadCast is the right ans for the question you have. you can use as below

```
Intent alarm_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                AlarmReceiver.class);
        // In reality, you would want to have a static variable for the request
        // code instead of 192837
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837,
                alarm_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
        long interval = 900 * 1000; //
        // Get the AlarmManager service
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                interval, sender);
```

Comment: Can SomeOne UpVote My Post in the Same Way(UnFair) somes Peoples DownVOted My Post ?

Comment: @Nikita : The question was down votes may be because it was unclear and patial. and admin has closed that too. still +1 from me

Comment: Thanks you , but i think this System is Unfair , as Anyone can Decide if the Question is Clear , Or Not

Comment: It was pretty unclear from first glance. so next time onward please be more specific and clear.

Comment: there is No 'Next Time' as i am Blocked and its Never Expire ...

Comment: i mean when you ask new question.